# How to keep this div visible ?

Tags: html, css

I made a tree into a div, it works fine.

When the tree is closed : it looks like that :

[image]

But when the tree is opened : i would like that all the div is visible :

[image]

You see on the picture that a part is hidden by the table, and that the tree is not completely visible.

The code is :

```
<div style="height:30px; overflow:visible; border: 1px solid #e5e6e7; background-color: #ffffff;    z-index:10;">

                <div id="arbre_json" ></div>
            </div>
```

I tried with "z-index" property , with "overflow" propery, without success. How could I do that ?

Thanks a lot for your responses. And have a nice day.

Dominique

Comment: Need way more information, [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: Without knowing the rest of your markup and styles (HTML + CSS), we won't be able to help you much beyond guessing. Please post your whole code, or a JSFiddle recreating the problem - or at least a live link.

Comment: If you use `position:absolute` you can set `z-index` to `99`

Answer (score -1):

Using js you can control the div's by using `.children`

https://api.jquery.com/children/